# Как из ListView вызывать соответствующие элементу списка описание в AlertDialog?

Tags: android

Начал делать первое приложение для Андроид. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: хочу чтобы при нажатии на элемент списка вызвался AlertDialog с описанием этого элемента. Для каждого элемента свой Title, icon, message (описание), либо же заменить message на textview. Помогите пожалуйста. Понятно что нужно загнать как-то это всё в массив, как - не понятно:) Вызов AlertDialog для одного элемента (вызываю при нажатии на TextView): 
 public void onShowDialog(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShotDrinks.this);

```
    builder.setTitle("Название")
            .setMessage("Какое-то описание")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setNegativeButton("Закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton ("Поделиться", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "_SUBJECT_");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "_BODY_");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.app_name)));
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто по нажатию на позицию списка вызывайте какой нибудь метод showDialog(), где в качестве параметров передайте нужные вам параметры - Title, icon, message, а внутри метода уже обрабайте создание и отображение AlertDialog

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String[] titles = new String [] {"первый", "второй", "третий"};
String[] messages = new String [] {"первый", "второй", "третий"};
int[] icons = new int [] {R.drawable.first, R.drawable.second,, R.drawable.third};

ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            createAndShowDialog(titles[position], messages[position], icons[position]);
        }
    });
}

public void createAndShowDialog(String title, String message, int drawable) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setIcon(drawable)
            .setNegativeButton("Закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton ("Поделиться", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "_SUBJECT_");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "_BODY_");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.app_name)));
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Comment: это понятно. но  у каждого элемента свое изображение и описание, и название! можете написать пример кода вызова?

Comment: Я так понимаю в виде списка вы используете ListView? если так напишите как вы его создаете и обрабатываете клик на позиции

Comment: не обрабатываю пока никак. не понятно как. public class Terminology extends ListFragment {

    public Terminology() {
    }

    String data[] = new String[] { "элементы списка"} @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

Comment: Переопределяй в своем классе метод onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id), и он сам за тебя все решить. Внутри метода ты уже можешь обращаться к v, которая и будет являться твоей строкой

Comment: list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        как тут вызвать метод onShowDialog для каждого элемента со своим заголовком, icon, message?
    }
});

Comment: Тогда вопрос - откуда эти "заголовок, icon, message" надо брать? они как раз являются составляющими позиции списка?

Comment: Делаю приложение для барменов. Элементы списка - название коктейлей, при нажатии выдается диалог в котором: title - название коктейля, icon - изображение, message - описание (рецепт приготовления)

Comment: setTitle("Название")
            .setMessage("Какое-то описание")
             .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

Comment: Ну тогда это уже к вам вопрос, где у вас хранятся эти данные? в базе данных, в файле, или просто в каком то массиве Drink[]

Comment: просто массив  данных String data[] = new String[] { "коктейль1", ...."коктейль n"}

Comment: тогда просто используй параметр position метода setOnItemClickListener для того, чтобы вырывать нужный элемент массива, и его передавай в метод для создания диалога, какого нибудь createAndShowDialog(String title, String message, int drawable). Поэтому как я понимаю тебе нужно три массива тогда, либо массив экземпляров класса Drink или что то в этом роде, тогда достаточно будет сделать метод в виде createAndShowDialog(Drink drink), а уже в классе Drink зашивай эти поля, заголовок, сообщение и картинку

Comment: я это понимаю, но не понимаю как) поэтому и написал сюда, изучаю андроид буквально три недели, в принципе, приложение практически готово, не считая внешнего вида. вот осталось реализовать данный метод. не могли бы Вы написать пример кода?

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ кусок кода, использовал там обычный ListView, так что уж сам поправь для ListFragment, я думаю разберешься

Comment: спасибо. сейчас попробую. далеко не уходи:)

Comment: где-то я накосячил) пишу public class ShotDrinks extends ListFragment.  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, title);
        setListAdapter(adapter);...... AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); ошибок не показывает, но при вызове данного пункта меню приложение вылетает

Comment: разобрался. спасибо тебе, Werder!

Comment: отлично! ;-) поставь плюсик если правда помогло )

Comment: как и где его ставить???

Comment: Рядом с ответом две стрелочки и значок что ответ верный )

Answer (score 1):

public class ShotDrinks extends ActionBarActivity {

```
String title[] = new String[]{"Б-52","Зеленый мексиканец","Оборотень","Аут","БМВ"};
String description[] = new String[]{"Бейлис, калуа, трипл сек","Текила, лимонный сок, пизан","лалалалал","Виски, коньяк, водка, самбука","текила, трипл сек, самбука"};
int[] icons = new int [] {R.drawable.b52, R.drawable.green_mexicano, R.drawable.oboroten, R.drawable.ayt, R.drawable.bmw};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shot_drinks);

    // Связываемся с ListView
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    // создаем адаптер
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, title);

    // устанавливаем адаптер списку
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            onShowDialog(title[position], description[position], icons[position]);
        }
    });
}

public void onShowDialog(String title, String message, int drawable){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setIcon(drawable)
            .setNegativeButton("Закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton ("Поделиться", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "_SUBJECT_");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "_BODY_");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.app_name)));
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}